# Как вывести и подсчитать данные из базы Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Мне нужно вывести названия категорий и количество записей данной категории как показано на фото ниже

[image: Categories]

Есть таблица **categories** где хранятся названия категорий

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `cat_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `cat_sort` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `categories` (`cat_id`, `cat_name`, `cat_sort`) VALUES
(1, 'Html', 1),
(2, 'Css', 2),
(3, 'Js', 3),
(4, 'Ajax', 4);
```

Есть таблица **blog** где хранятся записи

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `cat` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `blog` (`id`, `name`, `text`, `cat`) VALUES
(1, 'Заголовок статьи по CSS', 'Техст статьи по CSS', 2),
(2, 'Заголовок статьи по Html', 'Текст статьи по Html', 1),
(3, 'Заголовок статьи по Ajax', 'Текст статьи по Ajax', 4),
(4, 'Заголовок статьи по Ajax', 'Текст статьи по Ajax', 4);
```

Как правильно составить запрос в базу данных для того чтобы вывести названия категорий и количество записей в каждой категории одним запросом ?

Comment: Составить запрос, получить через него данные, вывести.

Comment: Критиковать могут все, а помочь только единицы, ведь критиковать очень легко.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f98ba/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `cat_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `cat_sort` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `categories` (`cat_id`, `cat_name`, `cat_sort`) VALUES
(1, 'Html', 1),
(2, 'Css', 2),
(3, 'Js', 3),
(4, 'Ajax', 4);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `cat` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `blog` (`id`, `name`, `text`, `cat`) VALUES
(1, 'Заголовок статьи по CSS', 'Техст статьи по CSS', 2),
(2, 'Заголовок статьи по Html', 'Текст статьи по Html', 1),
(3, 'Заголовок статьи по Ajax', 'Текст статьи по Ajax', 4),
(4, 'Заголовок статьи по Ajax', 'Текст статьи по Ajax', 4);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT c.cat_name, count(b.id) as count FROM categories c
left join blog b on b.cat = c.cat_id
GROUP BY b.cat
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f98ba/2/0)**:

```
| cat_name | count |
|----------|-------|
|       Js |     0 |
|     Html |     1 |
|      Css |     1 |
|     Ajax |     2 |
```

Comment: @alexander barakin ну ничего себе формат) здорово