# Как сделать запрос SQL с группировкой?

Tags: sql

Всем привет есть запрос

```
SELECT album.title, album.title, album.cover, album.cover_thumb
        FROM album
        WHERE album.id_artist=$id_artist
        ORDER BY title asc
```

Ну тут все просто. Так вот , есть вторая таблица Songs (Песни).

```
id
title
id_artist
id_album
```

Связь таблица album и songs по id_album. Нужен запрос, что бы получить кол-во песен у каждого альбома?
Т.е. есть один альбом. Допустим "Альбом 1". У него есть 3 песни. "Песня 1, Песня 2, Песня 3". Нужно получить все поля таблицы album и кол-во песен каждого альбома.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Как вывести и подсчитать данные из базы Mysql?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438389/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, такой запрос будет работать:

```
SELECT album.title, album.title, album.cover, album.cover_thumb, COUNT(songs.id) as sum
    FROM album
    LEFT JOIN songs
    ON songs.id_album = album.id_album
    WHERE album.id_artist=$id_artist
    GROUP BY songs.id_album
    ORDER BY album.title asc
```

P.S. У вас почем-то два раза title в селекте ;)

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш ответ верный!